# NLMO algorithm failed to converge

Tags: quantum-chemistry

I have been using NBO 7.0 software and the file.47, and the option in ORCA with nbo block and sometimes I have problems with the convergence algorithm for NLMO specifically this error: **NLMO algorithm could not converge**.

Do you have any way of solving this convergence problem?

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but since it has been almost 6 months, is there any update you can provide us? Are you still urgently or actively in need of an answer to this question? Please let us know!